# neDB database only loads on full restart Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron, nedb

So I switched from working on a mac to working on windows and this weird bug popped up. I have a database(Compendium) and on render of a React component I fire React.useEffect to call a function to pull out some information out of the database.
Here is my load function:

```
export function LoadRaces(callback) {
  const returnRaces: Race[] = [];
  const Datastore = require("nedb"),
    races = new Datastore({ filename: "Compendium.db" });
  races.loadDatabase();
  console.log("Preloading Races Test");
  races.find({ size: { $exists: true } }, function (err, docs) {
    console.log("Loading Races");
    docs.map((c) => {
      returnRaces.push(c);
      callback(returnRaces);
    });
  });
}
```

my UseEffect is rather simple:

```
{React.useEffect(() => {
                        LoadRaces((result) => {
                            DisplayRaces(result);
                        });
                    }, [])}
```

Here is the problem: When I first start my Electron app via npm run start the LoadRaces function runs how it's supposed to, prints out "Preloading Races Test" followed by "Loading Races" into the console, displays the races how it supposed to.
However when I reload the electron app(not close it just go ctrl-R or even force reload) the .find() of the LoadRaces does not run at all it seems.

Update: after more testing it looks like the database just doesn't load at all on the reload.